# Writing error in Beethoven's autograph of "moonlight" sonata?

Tags: piano, beethoven

In Beethoven's op. 27/2 in the autograph, bar 20, in the left hand on musical beat 1, the lower tone seems to be d sharp ("dis").

https://www.beethoven.de/en/media/view/6442239777570816/scan/0

In the printed versions (i.e., Wiener Urtext) there is an e sharp ("eis").

The latter seems to be intended, since it would be an octave as an harmonic interval.
I cannot believe that Beethoven made a writing error here(?)

What is the explanation?

Comment: Side note: use IMSLP for the originals. Not that it makes a difference, but it's slightly more reliable.

Comment: @10Rep Reliable in what way exactly? The Beethoven Haus in Germany seems pretty reliable to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beethoven made an error.

> **20.lh.1** Lower note is DD# [low D#] in all sources, a note that is harmonically absurd and was not even available on Beethoven's piano. It illustrates well the danger of placing too much faith in a composer's autograph score.

Cooper, Barry. 2007. *Beethoven: The 35 Piano Sonatas, Volume 2 — Commentaries*. London: ABRSM Publishing. Page 21.